# WPF DataGrid row and column Style question

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a need to highlight the MouseOver row of the datagrid, which seems to be easy with this style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The problem is that I also have a style for some readonly cells defined as:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As a result, those readonly cells don't get MouseOver background. How do I solve this conflict? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Coding style means the style in which code is writen. It does nor affect the style of the UI. Please see [this clarification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style).

Comment: @Monster Truck: I don't understand what you are talking about. Did I say coding style?

Comment: Yes, you had tagged it "coding-style". I edited your post and removed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a conflict. The MouseOver event is intended to work for normal row and cell which is not readonly.

You should add a MultiTrigger for this problem.

Sample:

```
  <MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true" />
      <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
  </MultiTrigger>
```

The code is valid for a style for DataGridCell. The completed code sample would be:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">    
<Style.Triggers>        
      <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true" />
          <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
      </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I just tried your idea and I got a compiler error: "Cannot find the Style Property 'IsReadOnly' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow'. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should out the above code inside a style for DataGridCell. I will edit and update the code above.

Comment: I don't thinking putting this trigger on DataGridCell will work, because it only highlights the current cell on mouse over, instead of the whole row.

Comment: You can't do that for DataGridRow, because DataGridRow doesn't have ReadOnly property. But you can make the DataGridRow disabled by setting the property Enabled to false, and then make the style using MultiTrigger above.

Comment: Making row disabled is different to readonly. When disabled, clicking row doesn't make it selected. I have the same problem for DataGridCells.